# How can i send verification email for a registration?

Tags: php, email

I have recently starting using php so i need your help.
I have created a contact form that sends an email to me after someone submits,but how can i send a copy of the email or a new email to the submitter also ?

Thank you in advance.

This is my html code where user enters his email:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_email">Email </label>
            <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the php code that sends an email to me :

```
<?php
$from = 'Someone <registration@registration.gr>';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = 'me <me@wxample.com>';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'Subject';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Ονομα', 'surname' => 'Επίθετο', 'need' => 'Need', 'title' => 'Τίτλος','specialty' => 'Ειδικότητα','foreas' => 'Φορέας','country' => 'Χώρα','city' => 'Πόλη','area' => 'Περιοχή','address' => 'Διευθυνση','tk' => 'T.K','tergasias' => 'Tηλ.Εργασίας','toikias' => 'Tηλ.Οικίας','mobile' => 'Κινητό','fax' => 'Φαξ','email' => 'Email'); 

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Successfull';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
```

Comment: _And this is the php code that sends an email to me_ I dont see any code that sends an email to anywhere

Comment: Change `$sendTo = 'someone <someone@somewhere.com>';` and then send it again

Comment: In my code i used my email instead of me@wxample.com.

Comment: please go through my answer.. you will surely get solution

Answer (score 0):

first of all request needs to be sent to php file , for example you send with parameter email=xyz@xyz.in through **GET** method,

generate a random number on php file save into a table with email

you can generate a random number by-

```
$randomcode=rand(100000,999999);
```

here i saved it to a variable named random code

now we can shoot that generating a url to email

```
$randomcode=rand(100000,999999);
$email=$_GET['email'];// storing email into a variable
$tempMail="verification@domain.com"; // --display on user email account
$to =$email;
$email_subject = "Verification of Email"; // you can enter anything else
$email_body = "http://www.somedomain.com/verifyemail.php?email=$email&code=$randomcode ,click above link to verify email";
$headers = "From: $tempMail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $tempMail";
$check=false;
// now we will send mail
$check = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
if($check){ //if success 
          }else{}
```

now you need to create a php document for verification of that email for example used above as **verifyemail.php** where php script will check if that random number is stored in table or not...

now user will get a email containing url, when he will click on that **verifyemail.php** will verify if these are present inn database or not, if yes then verification successful